# Center fixed-size ImageView horizontally in parent ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a rather simple layout: A `ConstraintLayout` filling the entire screen, with one big `CardView` that, at the top, has an `ImageView` that is half on the `CardView` and half above it (actually not half, but you get the point).

However, there are two issues: the `ImageView` sticks to the left of the parent and I do not know how to make it horizontally centered - all I can find on Google are chains for multiple elements, but I just want one centered.

The layout editor works extremely bad for me. My first complaint is that I seem to be unable to create constraints to the parent. Then I tried centering the `ImageView` horizontally in parent by pressing the button that says "Center in parent". This increases the `CardView`'s width, no effect at all on the `ImageView`.

While I am at it, how could I z-order the `ImageView` on top of the `CardView`?

Here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/re_zero"

    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#adjust-the-constraint-bias):

> When you add a constraint to both sides of a view (and the view size
>   for the same dimension is either "fixed" or "wrap content"), the view
>   becomes centered between the two anchor points by default.

Adding the following constraint centered the `ImageView`.

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
```

Also, adding a higher elevation than the `CardView` fixed the z-index, since the elevation overrides z-index.