# How to center align elements of a layout that is added by using <include/>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have created a simple layout that contains 2 `imageViews`.

This is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/root_team1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_one_IV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#004187"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/team_one_IV2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#004187"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/team_one_IV" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what its showing me when i view the layout.

[image]

Now i want to include this layout in another layout. This is what i did.

```
  <include
        android:id="@+id/firstTeam"
        layout="@layout/team_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and this is what i get after including this layout in another layout.

[image]

As you can see the layout is attached to the top, but i want it to be in the center of the container, i have defined container height to `300dp`. Do i need to use some other type of layout to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

Complete layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
    
    
        <include
            android:id="@+id/team_1"
            layout="@layout/team_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: post layout that you are including

Comment: @MaksymV. : I have updated the question. please check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center fixed-size ImageView horizontally in parent ConstraintLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883170/center-fixed-size-imageview-horizontally-in-parent-constraintlayout)

Answer (score 0):

So if the layout you are trying to include is the first layout in this post you have to options:

make those imageViews' width `wrap_content`

or add

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
```